# tf.summary.image provoks PNG encoding failed

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, tensorboard, libpng

I am working on MNIST dataset and having trouble with tensorboard. I want to record an image with the following function :

```
tf.summary.image('input', input_layer, 1)
```

But I get the following warning and error :

> 2018-11-04 19:32:44.798869: W tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc:87] PNG warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.34
>   2018-11-04 19:32:44.838003: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at summary_image_op.cc:131 : Internal: PNG encoding failed
>   2018-11-04 19:32:44.798869: W tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc:87] PNG warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.50 but running with 1.6.34
>   2018-11-04 19:32:44.838003: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at summary_image_op.cc:131 : Internal: PNG encoding failed

I read about the warning, it is possible that it is not a problem from what I read. 
What I cannot find out or understand is which is the "application" the warning is talking about, tensorflow ? tensorboard ? 
On of the advice I get from internet is to have the same version in my system than the one of the application. I want to update the one of the application.

Another point, to be sure that the input to tf.summary.image is fine, the following command :

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

`print(input_layer)`

Gives the following output :

> Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)

Which seems to correspond to the input requirement for the image function.

Could you please tell me if : 
- the issue is known
- or how to investigate the problem to be more independant next time (I am a bit lost about version investigation, what is installed or not, if I should check the version in python or in Linux).

Thank you in advance